# 400 error on username-password flow

Tags: c#, oauth, username

I'm implementing a partner system to an existing username-password oauth flow for SalesForce, and I'm trying to get the c# code to work.  I've been working with a standard WebRequest variant, which I've used often in the past.

The problem I'm getting is that, when I submit, the GetResponse() step throws a 400 error -- which means I get no more details back, as the response object is never retrieved.

Here's the code snippet:

```
  string post_data = "grant_type=password";
  post_data += "&client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE";
  post_data += "&client_secret=SECRET_HERE";
  post_data += "&username=USERNAME_HERE";
  post_data += "&password=PASSWORD_AND_SECURITY_TOKEN_HERE";

  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);
  request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
  using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
      requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
      requestStream.Close();
  }

  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  // 400 error occurs on this ^^ line
```

What's driving me completely bonkers, though, is that if I just copy/paste all the values from the above into a plain old HTML form that targets the same URL, and submit it, then I get the response coming back just fine.  So the values seem to be fine, and they should work -- but something is going wrong when I'm submitting via the HttpWebRequest.  I just can't see what, or why.

I've tried a variety of URL encodings on the data values (Server.URLEncode, HttpUtility.UrlEncode, HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode), all with absolutely no success.  And I've tried targetting the form and the code instead at a local page to examine the received data and headers, but couldn't find any significant differences beyond the header differences you'd expect, none of which appeared to be significant.

If anyone has run into this and found a solution, I'd love to hear it -- the place where the code needs to go rules out the threaded option, but I've tried a number of variants on this (including switching from HttpWebRequest to standard WebRequest, and trying out WebClient), all without any success.

Comment: This seems to be a TLS protocol issue. Salesforce disabled TLS1.0 last year. You have to use TLS1.1 and higher. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647591/error-with-salesforce-authentication-from-c-sharp-clients) from StackOverflow discussed a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks!  That solved my problem -- I thought the WebRequest was supposed to identify and use the highest available TLS, but I guess that wasn't working, as it worked perfectly after adding the explicit protocol. 

(Apparently I can't mark as solved because it's a comment, not an answer -- but thanks!)